# Reading multiple files in MASM 8086 Assembly

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, x86-16, masm

I want to make an animation in MASM and I've been doing this. How do I make this more efficient? Like making it into an array of strings? and how to access it once by using just a single address while incrementing it? I really need it because inside the main proc, my codes get out of bounds for being too hardcoded or far from each other

```
frame1FileName DB 'frame1.bin', 0
frame2FileName DB 'frame2.bin', 0
frame3FileName DB 'frame3.bin', 0
frame4FileName DB 'frame4.bin', 0
frame5FileName DB 'frame5.bin', 0
frame6FileName DB 'frame6.bin', 0
frame7FileName DB 'frame7.bin', 0
frame8FileName DB 'frame8.bin', 0
frame9FileName DB 'frame9.bin', 0
frame10FileName DB 'frame10.bin', 0
frame11FileName DB 'frame11.bin', 0
frame12FileName DB 'frame12.bin', 0
frame13FileName DB 'frame13.bin', 0
frame14FileName DB 'frame14.bin', 0
frame15FileName DB 'frame15.bin', 0
frame16FileName DB 'frame16.bin', 0
frame17FileName DB 'frame17.bin', 0
frame18FileName DB 'frame18.bin', 0
frame19FileName DB 'frame19.bin', 0
frame20FileName DB 'frame20.bin', 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Store all your ASCIIZ filenames in records that have the same length.

Here it means that the first 9 get padded with an extra zero. The recordsize becomes **12**.

```
frameFileName DB 'frame1.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame2.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame3.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame4.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame5.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame6.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame7.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame8.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame9.bin', 0, 0
              DB 'frame10.bin', 0
              DB 'frame11.bin', 0
              DB 'frame12.bin', 0
              DB 'frame13.bin', 0
              DB 'frame14.bin', 0
              DB 'frame15.bin', 0
              DB 'frame16.bin', 0
              DB 'frame17.bin', 0
              DB 'frame18.bin', 0
              DB 'frame19.bin', 0
              DB 'frame20.bin', 0
```

You can refer to the correct filename by calculating its offset within the table and adding that to the start of the table. `address = start + index * recordsize`.

If, working zero-based, the first filename gets index 0 and the 20th filename gets index 19, then the effective address for any particular filename is obtained from:

```
; BX is file index [0,19]
mov  ax, 12                  ;
mul  bx                      ; In 8086 there's no "IMUL BX, 12"
mov  bx, ax                  ;
lea  bx, [frameFileName + bx]
```

Or if you don't want to clobber `DX` and you're not going to need more than 255 files:

```
; AL is file index [0,19]
mov  ah, 12
mul  ah
mov  bx, ax
lea  bx, [frameFileName + bx]
```

### Use a template that you complete with a 2-digit number.

This will save a lot of space especially if the number of files increases. It could even require 3 or 4 digits.

```
frameFileName DB 'frame??.bin', 0

...

; AL is file index [1,20]
aam                          ; Divides AL by 10, Use this only if AL=[0,99]
add  ax, 3030h               ; Convert to text
xchg al, ah
mov  bx, offset frameFileName
mov  [bx+5], ax
```

Comment: You can also define the filenames table as a sequence of address references and maintain its count. I'm not quite clear on the masm syntax, but in fasm you can define text and use that definition label elsewhere as a lookup. Also, data structures like linked lists are very helpful, whether you are making your own, or using a library.

Comment: This is my code
https://github.com/JunnielRome/Animation/blob/main/chicken.asm

Comment: I'm not really good at this and I don't know how to debug my code. Storing all my ASCIIZ filenames in records that have the same length works but my frames skips then stops even though I'm just incrementing it by 1. I'm really thankful btw

Comment: Oh wait, I can see the problem now haha it was how I modified my count. EDIT: It now works! Thank you sir!

Comment: MUL is slow (on 8086), and 12 = 4 x 3 takes only one more instruction.  `mov bx, ax` / `add bx,bx` / `add bx, ax` (bx = ax * 3) / `shl bx,2` (bx = ax * 12).   32-bit mode is of course much better, `lea ebx, [eax + eax*2]` / `shl ebx,2` (or use `[filename + EBX*4]` as an addressing mode).  Also, not using MUL allows avoiding AX in the first place if that helps, but does need 2 regs...  If you start with the value in BX, `shl bx,2` / `lea ax, [bx + filename]` / `add ax, bx` / `add bx,ax` replaces a MOV with LEA with table address, but is more obfuscated / less obvious than MUL.

Comment: Or with better ILP on superscalar CPUs, and easier to grok: `shl bx,2` / `lea ax, [bx + filename]` / `add bx, bx` / `add bx,ax`.  So the final add has BX=`8*idx` and AX=`4*idx + filename` as inputs, doing 12 = 8 + 4.  None of this turned out to be very appropriate for a beginner answer, just an optimization that's not simpler than MUL.